# Python GEKKO Unexpected Behavior with Constraints

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I've been playing around with GEKKO for solving flow optimizations and I have come across behavior that is confusing me.

**Context:**

Sources --> [mixing and delivery] --> Sinks

I have multiple sources (where my flow is coming from), and multiple sinks (where my flow goes to). For a given source (e.g., SOURCE_1), the total flow to the resulting sinks must equal to the volume from SOURCE_1. This is my idea of conservation of mass where the 'mixing' plant blends all the source volumes together.

**Constraint Example (DOES NOT WORK AS INTENDED):**

When I try to create a constraint for the two SINK volumes, and the one SOURCE volume:

```
m.Equation(volume_sink_1[i] + volume_sink_2[i] == max_volumes_for_source_1)
```

I end up with weird results. With that, I mean, it's not actually optimal, it ends up assigning values very poorly. I am off from the optimal by at least 10% (I tried with different max volumes).

**Constraint Example (WORKS BUT I DON'T GET WHY):**

When I try to create a constraint for the two SINK volumes, and the one SOURCE volume like this:

```
m.Equation(volume_sink_1[i] + volume_sink_2[i] <= max_volumes_for_source_1 * 0.999999)
```

With this, I get MUCH closer to the actual optimum to the point where I can just treat it as the optimum. Please note that I had to change it to a `less than or equal to` and also multiply by `0.999999` which was me messing around with it nonstop and eventually leading to that.

Also, please note that this uses practically all of the source (up to 99.9999% of it) as I would expect. So both formulations make sense to me but the first approach doesn't work.

The only thing I can think of for this behavior is that it's stricter to solve for `==` than `<=`. That doesn't explain to me why I have to multiply by 0.999999 though.

Why is this the case? Also, is there a way for me to debug occurrences like this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This same improvement occurs with [complementary constraints for conditional statements](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ConditionalStatements) when using `s1*s2<=0` (easier to solve) versus `s1*s2==0` (harder to solve).

[image: if statement]

[image: complementary]

From the research papers I've seen, the justification is that the solver has more room to search to find the optimal solution even if it always ends up at `s1*s2==0`. It sounds like your problem may have multiple local minima as well if it converges to a solution, but it isn't the global optimum.

If you can post a complete and minimal problem that demonstrates the issue, we can give more specific suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I've compared my gekko attempts with my PSO version, and they have identical results.

I will have to make reminder for myself that I should try to use `<=` instead of `==` when it is possible.